# Spring data query limit as parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to do something like this using native query:

```
@Query(value = "select * from systems where UPPER(system_name) like UPPER('%?1%') ORDER BY system_name LIMIT '?2'", nativeQuery = true)
List<System> findAllBySystemNameWithLimit(String systemName, int limit);
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to use limit as parameter? Thanks for answer.

Comment: What is your underlying database, and what do you exactly mean by 'It doesn't work'?

Comment: Yes, i've already fixed that, I've just forgot that there is no limit in Oracle db. :D But the concat didn't work too, i must do it with ||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `?1` or `:paramname` you don't have to use them between two quotes like you do 
`'%?1%'` and `'?2'` so instead your query should look like :

```
select * from systems 
   where UPPER(system_name) like UPPER(CONCAT('%', ?1, '%')) ORDER BY system_name LIMIT ?2
   //------------------------------^-----^-----^----^---^-------------------------------^^
```

Comment: but the problem is with limit parameter, not the first one

Comment: what is the problem with that problem @Helosze you just pass a param like the first one so i don't see any problem here

Comment: The problem was that in oracle there is no limit and i forgot about that. :D But this concat doesn't work for me (shouldn't there be 2 concats for every 2 parameters?). I've solved this by using || to concat strings.

Comment: @Helosze i thought you are using mysql ;)